# Spring Test Wants To Connect to Database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, jpa, mockmvc

I am trying to write some tests for my application and encountered following problem:
I defined a application-test.yml with folling content:

```
server:
  port: 8085

spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
            resourceserver:
                jwt:
                    # change localhost:8081 with container name
                    issuer-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/drivingschool
                    jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/drivingschool/protocol/openid-connect/certs

keycloak:
    realm: drivingschool
    auth-server-url: http://localhost:8081/auth
    ssl-required: external
    resource: client-interface
    use-resource-role-mappings: true
    credentials:
        secret: xxx
    bearer-only: true
```

My test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class StudentControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private StudentService service;

    @MockBean
    private StudentRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads(){}
//more tests
}
```

the test all pass green BUT in the log i can see, that my app tries to connect to a database configured in my (basic) application.yml.

```
ava.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=9005)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:9005. Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt (Connection refused)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.6.1.jar:na]
```

```
jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
      hibernate:
        use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
        ddl-auto: create

    datasource:
      url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:9005/waterloo
      username: waterloo
      password: xxx
      driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

when creating a application-prod.yml and moving all content from application.yml to application-prod.yml it tells me I have to configure a datasource URL

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I have the following questions:

1. Do the application.yml files get layered (*-test.yml  settings on top of application.yml)?
2. Why does Spring try to build a connection to my database when I am not setting a datasource on my application-test.yml AND mocking the repository on the test?
3. Is it normal that Spring trys to establish a connection at this part?
   3.1) If not: How to i prevent it from doing so?

Thanks and kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missed following annotation:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Great :-) Dont forget to mark my answer as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

> Failed to determine a suitable driver class

You need to add mariadb driver dependency to your gradle or maven file.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.6.2

Make sure that dependency scope is suitable for test

If you already have and its still not working try to clean and rebuild your project.

Your Questions:

> Do the application.yml files get layered (*-test.yml settings on top
> of application.yml)?

If you add `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to you TestClass Spring will try to find an application-test.yml and overrrides application.yml properties with the given properties

> Why does Spring try to build a connection to my database when I am not
> setting a datasource on my application-test.yml AND mocking the
> repository on the test?

Thats the magic of spring boot - it has default configurations for everything. You just need to set the Datasource properties and it will create the bean by itself.

> Is it normal that Spring trys to establish a connection at this part? 3.1) If not: How to i prevent it from doing so?

You are starting the whole spring context with @SpringBootTest Annotation.
So it will startup all Repositories and try to establish connection to your database. If you don't want spring to startup the database layer you can just use @WebMvcTest

eg:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class StudentControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads(){}

    //more tests
}
```

Check this out: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

If you need to startup the whole SpringContext you can also disable Spring Data AutoConfiguration with:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Check this out: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-disable-auto-config

Comment: here is the dependency:
```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

It shouln't establish the connection in testing in the first place, thats what i am trying to figure out :(

Comment: You are starting the whole spring context with SpringBootTest Annotation
If you don't want spring to startup the database layer you can just use WebMvcTest Annotation
Check this out: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: I cannot start it with WebMvcTest because I need Keycloak and security filter to work. The answers under my last stack overflow question I asked him they told me to use the @SpringBootTest :s

Comment: Ok - and why dont you want to establish a database connection?
You could integrate a H2 imemory db in your test and just startup whole spring context

Comment: Did you tried to exclude Spring Data Autoconfiguration
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-disable-auto-config

Comment: I added the H2 database to application-test.properties, and yet it tries to connect to the database, and find the database configuration